# Python algorithm for creating flowcharts from excel data

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a .xls with some subjects I have to attend during my graduation. Some of these have recommendations (ex: Calculus II needs Calculus I) and their credits as well. I need to create a flowchart based on this one:

[image: Example Flowchart]

I had the ideia of importing to Python via Pandas and creating a dictionary with the following elements:

```
sub = {"Subject_Name":["Requirements","Credits"]}
```

And then, from that dictionary, I'd like to create a flowchart that automatically linked all subjects and their requirements just like the example image.
I've read about some tools from graphs like: GraphTool, graphviz and PythonCallGraph.

An example of a dictonary with the info that I have:

```
sub = {'Dynamics II':['Dynamics I','4'],'Aerodynamics I':['Fluid Mechanics','5']}
```

I've no ideia if the project will be that simple but I'd like to get a starting point!

Comment: Is it the graph you need primarily?

Comment: Yes, I'll rewrite my question later when I get back for clarity, but the graph is what I need

Comment: graphviz can generate the graph for you if you describe it in it's dot language.

I could share a snippet if you add few more nodes to populate the example.

Comment: I'e added some code to give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the graph you desire directly in Excel without writing any code if you use “Excel to Graphviz” which you can download at https://sourceforge.net/projects/relationship-visualizer/

Here is a screen print of a similar graph. 
[image: pic]

The spreadsheet used to create it resides in the “samples” directory in the zip file download.